# Running a .NET core app (.dll) with cmd by using process.start

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msdn

I'm new to .NET Core 2.0, so i might be doing this all wrong, if so let me know.

I have a .NET core 2.0 app that should be cross platform, hence the app is a .dll console application, and it does work fine on all platforms.

I'm trying to implement kind of a watchdog, that in case of necessary process will duplicate itself, and by the same way it was called

```
> $ dotnet process.dll
```

My code is:

```
var process = new Process
{
   StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
       FileName = "dotnet",
       Arguments = "path\release\PublishOutput\proces.dll"
       UseShellExecute = true,
       RedirectStandardOutput = false,
       RedirectStandardError = false,
       CreateNoWindow = true
     }

 };

 process.Start();
```

The problem is that when the process runs this code, i'm getting the following exception

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sometoken' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I can't find any mention of ruining dotnet from code, and i don't know even if this is possible?

Is it possible? Is .NET core process able to duplicate itself?

Thanks

Comment: Can I call this code using .NET Core API ? (.NET Core 2.1) I can't get it to work

Comment: Microsoft recommends to set UseShellExecute = false for Core Apps

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you also need to set the WorkingDirectory to `path\release\PublishOutput\` to be sure it is running in the same environment as calling `dotnet process.dll` directly in the console