# Different dotnet test results from cmd.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cmd

What I'm trying to achieve: I want to use a web application to run all the tests on my local windows PC.

I am using the following command:

```
c:/code/myRepo && dotnet test
```

I have tried the following command through run:

```
cmd.exe /C "c:/code/myRepo && dotnet test"
```

which runs successfully and all my tests pass.

I now want to run this from my .net Core application as so:

```
public static string RunCommand( string cmd)
{
    var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = $"/C \"{escapedArgs}\"",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    return result;
}
```

When I run the tests from here the tests run, but they all fail.

Question: there is something different between these 2 environments but I have no idea what, how /what can I check what might be different. I've tried the command:

```
set
```

and can't see anything obviously affecting the environment

Comment: You don't need `cmd.exe` to execute a command line application. Just run the application. `cmd.exe /C` starts *another* console with whatever arguments you passed to it. What you're trying to do will start one console that starts another console that finally runs `dotnet` with the arguments you provided. Just start `dotnet` instead

Comment: As [this probably duplicate question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326217/running-a-net-core-app-dll-with-cmd-by-using-process-start), all you need to do is call `dotnet` as the application and pass the option or  path to the dll. Just make sure it's run on the correct working directory. You could even use `Process.Start("dotnet","test")` if your program is in the correct working directory

Comment: thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. The program i am running is in a different scope to the tests. My application is programmatically running the tests from many other solutions that are not linked

Comment: That sounds like an XY problem - how to test multiple projects. As for the current question, you still don't need `cmd`. Either add the path to the project file as the last of the arguments, or set the `WorkingDirectory` in `ProcessStartInfo` to the folder where the project file is

Comment: As for the *actual* problem, you could use a build script eg written in [FAKE](https://fake.build/) or [CAKE](https://cakebuild.net/) to find and run all tests. You could even use a Powershell or CMD script to just find all `*.csproj` files under a root folder and pass them as arguments to `dotnet run`.

Comment: [Check this as well](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6572#issuecomment-300921019). I'm not sure if that still works, but you may be able to crete a `proj` file that finds all csproj files and runs test on them